# Change machine name

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to change a machine name for one of my CentOS servers. How would one go about changing it from saying:

`user@XXXXXX` (where I want to change what the XXXXX is)

Also if I change what the `XXXXX` is will someone be able to take the IP address of the server and figure out the new `XXXXX`?

Thanks.

Comment: You may get more help by posting to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I don't recommend server fault for questions like this (they'd consider it to basic/off topic), super user or the [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) are more appropriate.

Comment: Is there some guide as to which site to post on for which questions?

Comment: You kind of just need to read what each site is about. It can be hard to tell sometimes. Stack Overflow is generally for programming questions, and depending on how you phrase your question, it's not programming related. Whether to put it on Server Fault, Super User, or Unix & Linux isn't super clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`hostname`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hostname) command to change the hostname for the current session (it'll revert after you reboot) and edit `/etc/hostname` to change it permanently. You'll want to use both for the best results, as editing `/etc/hostname` doesn't change anything until you reboot.

E.g:

```
hostname newhost.example
echo "newhost.example" > /etc/hostname
```

These both need to be run as the `root` user.

Comment: Can someone take the IP address of the server and get the hostname from it?

Comment: Yes, but you have to provide the hostname via a [PTR record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup). They can't determine the hostname you set on the box without it.

Comment: I see, so without the PTR record, the hostname of the machine is completely private and local.

Comment: Correct. It's possible it may be exposed via software daemons that are listening on public ports, e.g. SSH, but thats it.